# How to disable multiple login from different computer using the same account PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

good evening. I am developing a website in which there is a constraint wherein it is not allowed to have multiple login in different computers with the same account. Can i achieve this using codeigniter? if not? How can i address this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How I approached that problem in a project was:

1. I grabbed the session id of the user once they logged in and stored it in the database.
2. Whenever the user logs in you grab the session id stored in the database and destroy it.

This will ensure that whenever they log in from another browser or computer their previous session is destroyed.

Here's some example code on the login page I did this:

```
session_commit();
session_id(session_create_id());
session_start();
//followed by other code
```

Using session_create_id function will create a unique session id because it checks if the one it's creating exists.

Next:

```
$query = "UPDATE user_table SET sess_id = ? WHERE id = ? AND sess_id = '0'";

$query_run = $database->prepare($query);

if($query_run->execute([session_id(), $user_id])):
    if($query_run->rowCount() < 1){
        $query = "SELECT sess_id FROM user_table WHERE id = ?";

        $query_run = $database->prepare($query);

        if($query_run->execute([$user_id])){
            //custom session destroy function
            session_destroy_client($query_run->fetchAll()[0]['sess_id']);

            $query = "UPDATE user_table SET sess_id = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $query_run = $database->prepare($query);
            $query_run->execute([session_id(), $user_id]);
        }
    }
endif;
```

Let the default value of the sess_id be zero. Whenever the user logs out set it to zero. But whenever they log in you still need to check if they have a session id stored in the database then destroy that session. This is what the custom destroy session looks like:

```
function session_destroy_client(string $id){
        // 1. commit session if it's started.
        if (session_status() != \PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
            session_write_close();
        }
        ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
        // 2. store current session id
        session_start();
        $cid = session_id();
        session_write_close();

        // 3. hijack then destroy session specified.
        session_id($id);
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();

        // 4. restore current session id. If you don't restore it, your current session will refer to the session you just destroyed!
        session_id($cid);
        session_start();
    }
```

That should work. You can add your custom function to a class if you would like and add features that would suit your need.